# Preventing Page Review after Logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, back-button, browser-history

This is a very famous questions in Google. I found several suggestion to achieve this feature. The procedure I have implemented is described below:

I have added a Logout Link in the home page and on clicking that link I am redirecting user to the logout page.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {      
    Response.Redirect("../Logout.aspx");
}
```

Now in the Logout.aspx I have added:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

in the Page_Load method code behind.

Also I have added a `asp:ScriptManager` and a `asp:Timer` to that `Logout.aspx`:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
</asp:ScriptManager> 
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" > 
</asp:Timer>
```

The Timer1_Tick method is:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

This is redirecting to the `Login.aspx` from `Logout.aspx`. Also I have added the following JavaScript method in the `Logout.aspx`:

```
function disableBackButton() {
    window.history.forward(1);
}
disableBackButton();
window.onload = disableBackButton();
window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) disableBackButton() }
window.onunload = function () { void (0) }
```

And it is working, only if I single click the Back button, or click multiple times with pause. But if it is being clicked multiple times consecutively then I am again being placed in the Home page.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following logout, where i clear the cookies, and i have not had any problems login-out my users "for real".

**Edit**:

Note that the browser often cache the pages in its history, and i do not think that you can prevent them from showing the pages, after a logout!

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();

// clear authentication cookie
HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

// clear session cookie
HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a useful method and I am going to use it. But this doesn't solve my problem. Is there any way to clear the cache completely or disable it.

Comment: It has been solved. I set no-cache to the home page (similar procedure used in the Page_Load of Logout.aspx). Perhaps I need to set no-cache option to the Master page's Page_Load, since it is inherited by the home page. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to the Master page's Page_Load along with the other techniques described in the question:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

It will work.